# Can you use module.exports with a class instantiation with new?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using the following pattern to build my `express` app. When I match a route, I like to delegate to an object that is an instance of a particular class, designed to handle that kind of request. It looks like this

server.js:

```
app.get('/myroute', require('myRoute'));
```

myRoute.coffee:

```
iMyRouteHandler = (req, res) ->
  new MyRouteHandler(req, res)

class MyRouteHandler
  constructor: (@req, @res) ->
    # Do some other preparation
    @send_response()

  send_response: =>
    if @req.param('something') is 'interesting'
      @res.send 'Something interesting'
    else
      @res.send 'Something boring'

module.exports = iMyRouteHandler
```

I'd love to hear any comments on my "design pattern" here, but my question is about the `module.exports`. Since I want to instantiate a class (that is, invoke the function via `new`), I can't simply pass its name back as the callback for express: I have to do this workaround. Is there a way to skip all this? Maybe I could pass `MyRouteHandler.constructor` as a callback? That sounds like a potentially bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to slice this up but my main comment about this pattern would be that you'd really need to have a compelling reason to go OOP with this, as it's a perfect use case for functional programming.

But if you want to stick with it you might do this variation, which is nearly the same thing, but mildly more coherent (IMHO):

```
class MyRouteHandler
  constructor: (@req, @res) ->
    # Do some other preparation
    @send_response()

  send_response: =>
    if @req.param('something') is 'interesting'
      @res.send 'Something interesting'
    else
      @res.send 'Something boring'

module.exports = (req, res) ->
  new MyRouteHandler(req, res)
```